# How to implement pagination in android using json from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am building an android app that fetches large amounts of data from server using json. I have recently come across CWAC endless adapter which simplifies the task of implementing the adapter myself. Also I have read about the limit clause in mysql if I use limit m,n the server will read m+n records to serve n records that I ask for. which can also be time consuming. Is there a way to fetch records from server and keep the time as little as possible. I have seen many apps do it but I am not sure how to do it. Please give me your suggestions as to how to best implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean implement cache ??

Comment: what do you mean by "keep the time as little as possible"?

Comment: if the server reads m+n records to serve n records then the access time will grow progressively with each query. Actually I am a little confused on this issue as to what is best.

Comment: I mean is it ok to use limit m,n clause or is there some other solution.

Comment: @Pankaj do you have access to the server code? Can you modify how the server receive the request and response?

Comment: The server is maintained by our Linux admins. I am sure I can get them to modify it. And PHP scripts are handled by our PHP developers and I can get them to modify the code.